# Construct an appropriate pivot using $Y(n)$ and $\theta$.

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

$Y_1,...,Y_n$ denote a random sample of size $n \geq 4$ from distribution with density function: $f(y)= 4 y^3/\theta^4$, 0

involving an unknown parameter $\theta$, ($\theta>0$). $Y(n)= \max \{ Y_1, \ldots ,Y_n \}$. How would I construct an appropriate pivot using $Y(n)$ and $\theta$?

Also, utilizing the pivot, construct a two-sided 1-alpha confidence interval for $\theta$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you solve this for a simpler but related problem?

Comment: Density function for what values of $y$? Must mention the support. Then can you find the distribution of $Y_{(n)}$?

Comment: support is 0<y<theta